# Need explanation of this UML model

Tags: java, uml

[image]
Please explain what "MANAGER static employee" means.
I did everything except *changeManager*, how can I implement it ?

```
 public  Employee(){
    this.id=-1;
    this.year=-1;
    salary=-1; 
    name="NA";
    department="NA";

}
public  Employee(int id ,String name ,String depatment, int year,double salary){
    Employee Employee=new Employee();

    Employee.setid(id); Employee.setname(name); Employee.setdepartment(depatment); Employee.setyear(year); Employee.setsalary(salary);
}
```

Comment: `MANAGER: static employee` = a variable named Manager of type employee

Comment: btw. Java isn't the same as JavaScript, you probably should choose one of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in Java a *static* attribute in UML is an attribute of the class itself, rather than an attribute of instance, that means there is only *one* manager 'shared' by all the instances. Of course its type is *Employee*, so in Java :

```
private static Employee MANAGER;
```

by default the class has no manager because *MANAGER* is *null*.

Note the presence of 'static' in the diagram is abnormal and does not follow the norm, like for the operation *changeManager* the line for the attribute is underlined, that is the way to say an attribute/operation is *static* in UML

The definition of *isManager* is trivial :

```
public boolean isManager() { return this == MANAGER; }
```

Note may be the class does not have yet a manager, in that case *MANAGER* is *null*, and to call *isManager(null)* is the way to check if the class has a manager

The definition of *changeManager* is also trivial :

```
public static void changeManager(Employee newManager) { MANAGER = newManager; }
```

Note that allows to have no manager calling that operation with *null*

---

Example with few methods/attributes :

**Employee.java**

```
class Employee {
  private String name;
  private int id;

  private static Employee MANAGER;

  public Employee(String n, int i) {
    name = n;
    id = i;
  }

  public boolean isManager() {
    return this == MANAGER;
  }

  public static void changeManager(Employee e) {
    MANAGER = e;
  }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Employee e1 = new Employee("e1", 1);
    Employee e2 = new Employee("e2", 2);

    System.out.print("e1.isManager() = ");
    System.out.println(e1.isManager());

    System.out.print("e2.isManager() = ");
    System.out.println(e2.isManager());

    System.out.println("do 'Employee.changeManager(e1)'");
    Employee.changeManager(e1);

    System.out.print("e1.isManager() = ");
    System.out.println(e1.isManager());

    System.out.print("e2.isManager() = ");
    System.out.println(e2.isManager());

    System.out.println("do 'Employee.changeManager(e2)'");
    Employee.changeManager(e2);

    System.out.print("e1.isManager() = ");
    System.out.println(e1.isManager());

    System.out.print("e2.isManager() = ");
    System.out.println(e2.isManager());

    System.out.println("do 'Employee.changeManager(null)'");
    Employee.changeManager(null);

    System.out.print("e1.isManager() = ");
    System.out.println(e1.isManager());

    System.out.print("e2.isManager() = ");
    System.out.println(e2.isManager());
  }
}
```

Compilation, execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ javac Main.java Employee.java 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ java Main
e1.isManager() = false
e2.isManager() = false
do 'Employee.changeManager(e1)'
e1.isManager() = true
e2.isManager() = false
do 'Employee.changeManager(e2)'
e1.isManager() = false
e2.isManager() = true
do 'Employee.changeManager(null)'
e1.isManager() = false
e2.isManager() = false
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211918/discussion-on-answer-by-bruno-need-explanation-of-this-uml-model).